# WMI Performance Adapter function for Chrome browser?

Tags: network, web-browser, chrome, ports, windows-10

Does someone know why the WMI Performance Adapter (WmiApSrv.exe) always starts when launching Chrome browser? Whats the function of this service?

I have heared this service can be maliciously used to "communicate" through the internet via open ports?

When I forcefully end this process in the taskmanager, Chrome keeps running perfectly, without issues.

Could it be that this WMI process is needed because one of Chrome's features called "Conceal local IP addresses with mDNS hostnames"?

Thanks